# Indirect Function in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2016

How to use Indirect Function to get data from another sheet from a single cell?
It's very confusing whether to use apostrophe or not. If someone could explain it with the Concept it would be of great help.

Comment: apostrophe is only require I belief if there is a space in the reference sheet name.  If there are no spaces, you can still use the apostrophe but it is not required

Comment: Please refer to this support article about **INDIRECT** function: https://www.contextures.com/xlFunctions05.html

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example:

```
=INDIRECT("'" & A1 & "'!" & A2)
```

[image]

Using the single quotes in the formula allows us to change the worksheet name in cell **A1** without having to change the formula.